# How can I toggle the button in real time when liking and disliking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

It seemed like something that'd be straightforward to accomplish, but I'm kind of struggling with this. The current behavior with the code below correctly increments likes/dislikes on each photo upon clicking any specific photo, but *not* the like/dislike state upon clicking which's what needs to be done to toggle between the Like and Dislike buttons.

Just like the functionality as Instagram - How can I make it so that the green like button (`success`) is displayed when the respective photo *isn't* liked.

And similarly, display the red dislike button (`danger`) when the respective photo *is* liked?

Below I tried to only use the `setUserClickedLike()` hook in both `handleLike()` and `handleDislike()` but it doesn't work.

```jsx
const Grid = () => {
  let authToken = localStorage.getItem("token");

  const [gridData, setGridData] = useState([]);

  // User clicks likes
  const [userLikedPhotos, setUserLikedPhotos] = useState({});

  const [userClickedLike, setUserClickedLike] = useState(false);
  const [userClickedDislike, setUserClickedDisliked] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };

    axios
      .get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/get-user-uploads-data", { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
        setGridData(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  const handleLike = (likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId) => {
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/like";

    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };

    let data = {
      UserID: likedPhotoUserId,
      userName: userName,
      likedPhotoId: likedPhotoId,
    };

    userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId] = true;

    gridData.find(function (photo) {
      setUserClickedLike(photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId);
      return photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId;
    }).likes++;

    axios
      .post(url, data, { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        setDataFromUserLikesTable(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    setUserLikedPhotos({ ...userLikedPhotos });
  };

  const handleDislike = (likedPhotoUserId, userName, likedPhotoId) => {
    const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/dislike";

    const headers = {
      Accept: "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${authToken}`,
    };

    let data = {
      UserID: likedPhotoUserId,
      userName: userName,
      dislikedPhotoId: likedPhotoId,
    };

    // dislike
    delete userLikedPhotos[likedPhotoUserId];
    gridData.find(function (photo) {
      setUserClickedLike(photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId);
      return photo.UserID === likedPhotoUserId;
    }).likes--;

    axios
      .post(url, data, { headers })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });

    setUserLikedPhotos({ ...userLikedPhotos });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="img-container">
          {gridData.map((photos, index) => {
            return (
              <>
                <div className="userDetails">
                  <span className="likesAmt">❤️ {photos.likes}</span>
                  <br />
                  {!photos.is_liked && !userClickedLike ? (
                    <Button
                      variant="success"
                      onClick={() =>
                        handleLike(
                          photos.UserID,
                          photos.name,
                          photos.photo_id,
                          photos.is_liked
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      Like
                    </Button>
                  ) : (
                    <Button
                      variant="danger"
                      onClick={() =>
                        handleDislike(
                          photos.UserID,
                          photos.name,
                          photos.photo_id,
                          photos.is_liked
                        )
                      }
                    >
                      Dislike
                    </Button>
                  )}
                </div>
              </>
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Grid;
```

Comment: Check if the photo is already liked by this user

Comment: Seems like your photos already have an `is_liked` indicator for each photo in your `gridData`. Maybe try to just edit the gridData whenever a user clicks on the like/dislike button? change the is_liked from true/false and set it back to gridData. This way you don't need those two states you are using.